# String Manipulation: convert flat string to a tree-like format

Tags: python, json, string, tree, format

I have this tree:

```
Active Mode
   |___ Local (EU)
   |       |___ <Random String>
   |___ International (WW)
   |       |___ <Random String> (I want this random string!!!)
Passive Mode
   |___ Local (EU)
   |       |___ <Random String>
   |___ International (WW)
           |___ <Random String>
```

But due to circumstances, my python will see it as a flat string:

```
Active Mode
Local (EU)
<Random String>
International (WW)
<Random String> (I want this random string!!!)
Passive Mode
Local (EU)
<Random String>
International (WW)
<Random String>
```

Note:  is basically a random string that I don't know what it is.

Now it's pretty easy to get the line I want, I just do `string.split(\n)[4]`. The tricky part is:

- the parents (`Active Mode` and `Passive Mode`) can be shuffled so the `Active Mode` would be *after* `Passive Mode`
- the children (`Local (EU)` and `International (WW)`) can also be shuffled
- A Parent might be missing or a child might be missing (so there is a chance that there is no `Active Mode` which means I should get something like `None`

One possible solution I thought of was to somehow convert the *flat string* into a multi-layer dictionary, list or json but I don't know how am I suppose to do it.

Comment: Can you have the line you want and not the line International (WW)?

Comment: I did not understand you. If you are asking whether the line "International (WW)" is a line that I can control or not then no. "Active Mode", "Passive Mode", "International (WW)" and "Local (EU)" are predefined variable that won't change. However their **order** or their **presence** can vary. Other lines are some variable that I don't know. (hope that I make sense)

Comment: I was asking something like this:Active Mode
Local (EU)
I don't want this line
I want this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sketched some code, however it might be dangerous, since there is no guarantee in general, that *random strings* within modes don't collide with titles and/or mode names:

```
def parse(text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    out = {}
    mode, options = None, None
    for l in filter(None, lines):
        if l.endswith(' Mode'):  # must be really careful here
            out[l] = out.get(l, {})
            mode = out[l]
            options = None
            continue

        # and here...
        if l.startswith('Local (') or l.startswith('International ('):
            mode[l] = mode.get(l, [])
            options = mode[l]
            continue

        options.append(l)

    return out

t = '''
Active Mode
Local (EU)
<Random String>
International (WW)
<Random String> (I want this random string!!!)
Passive Mode
Local (EU)
<Random String>
International (WW)
<Random String>
'''

print(parse(t))
```

The idea of the `parse()` function is to keep track of the current modes in local variables `mode` and `options`. At the same time it maintains a complete resulting object in the `out`.